# Can I put Splash & Icons out side the www folder?

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk

I am creating an application using the **intelXDK** tool. In that splash screens and app icons are taking too much space, almost 75%.

Is there any way in **intelXDK**, that I can include all the icons and splash screen but size of app remain in control. or can I put the splash & icons in specific plugin folder so that I can reduce the size?

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of the XDK those files must be inside the www folder. We are working on a solution for a future release, but no ETA on when that will happen.

You say they are taking up 75% of the space. How big is your complete app? My experience has been that they typically only require about 500k (1/2 Meg) of space.